# rewrite a recursion function with loop in python

Tags: python, recursion

I want to replace my function `foo` with `foo2`(non-resursion), but `foo2` works incorrect.
What's wrong with `foo2`?

```
def foo(n, k=0,s=0):
    if k < n:
        for i in xrange(k==0,10):
            foo(n, k+1, 10*s + i)
    else: 
        print s,

def foo2(n):
    s=0
    for k in xrange(n):
        st = s
        for i in xrange(k==0, 10):
            st = 10* st + i
        print st
foo(3)
foo2(3)
```

**Updated**

If I replace `10*s + i` with `s + i**3`, How can I rewrite it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo` prints 10<sup>n-1</sup> ~ 10<sup>n</sup>-1; Iterate `xrange(10**(n-1), 10**n)`.

```
def foo2(n):
    for s in xrange(10**(n-1), 10**n):
        print s,
```

---

Following is a translation of the recursive funciton using stack:

```
def foo2(n):
    stack = [(0, 0)] # corresponding to (..., k=0, s=0)
    while stack:
        k, s = stack.pop(0)
        if k < n:
            for i in xrange(k==0, 10):
                stack.append((k+1, 10*s + i))
        else:
            print s,
```

**NOTE** To implement strictly equivalent iterative version, you should also push iterator (`xrange...`); consume only one item at a time in a loop.